# Netbeans color scheme

Tags: php, debugging, netbeans, netbeans-7

In netbeans,

1. how can I change line highlighting background color while debugging?

   [image]

   "green line"
2. I love dark background and light foreground working areas. Is there
   any color theme like sublime or something "comfortable" for eyes for
   netbeans? What's your choice?

Comment: The Tools>Options>Font and Colors section has 5 tabs with different options in each.  I am not sure which highlight this is specifically referring to, so I can't direct you to the correct tab/option.

Comment: I want to know exact place, played with them, no success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tools > Options > Font and Colors > Highlighting > Highlight Caret Row >`

Comment: I think this is for the caret row as the name suggests. I couldn't find anything for the row debugger highlights seems light green as default and its impossible to see the row with dark themes.

Answer (score 0):

Tools > Options > Font and Colors > Annotations ...

Many options here apply.
Program counter and a Breakpoint
Current Program Counter

When you are on the breakpoint, hover over the breakpoint symbol and it will tell you what setting to change.